# Stripe amount button with text field

Tags: php, html, stripe-payments

I am using Strip custom code to create a button, by which customers might input the amount they want to pay.  The button amounts say a specific amount, though.. How do I change it to allow the user to input the amount they want to send?

Someone recommended I use a "post/php" form which I uploaded to my site for the "amount".  Then, I embedded the custom Stripe button in with my test link.  But, it returns a "404 error message".  Help!  Please??? can you email me?  sensmann@comcast.net.  Thanks!

How do I get the "amount" they type in on the form into my Stripe code, then? I embedded the Stripe code in my form... assuming that's what I was supposed to do.

Check it out: http://www.allrightmoves.com/contact-us.html ... The "post" form on the bottom is what I just did... The "purchase" button  is the stripe code.  Will get rid of the paypal jazz as soon as I can get this running.

This is all my *code* so far:

```
<div class="content">
    <form action="myform.php" method="post">Name/Company:
        <input name="name" type="text" size="55" />
        <br />Service:
        <input name="course" type="text" size="65" />
        <br />Price:
        <input name="price" type="text" size="20" />
        <br />
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
        <script>
            $('#customButton').click(function () {
                var token = function (res) {
                    var $input = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
                    $('form').append($input).submit();
                };

                StripeCheckout.open({
                    key: 'pk_test_9YvLQYPwXd8AgYccZxUcCSXR',
                    address: true,
                    amount: $_POST["price"],
                    currency: 'usd',
                    name: 'All Right Moves, LLC',
                    description: 'Professional Unpack Services',
                    panelLabel: 'Checkout',
                    token: token
                });

                return false;
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
<?php $name=$ _POST[ "name"]; $price=$ _POST[ "price"]; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $name; ?>
</body>
```

Really appreciate your help!!!
Thanks!
Suz

Comment: It seems there is no 'myform.php' file , did you check this?

Answer (score -1):

Stripe is a two step system. On the client side, a token is created and then passed to the server. On the server, the actual payment is processed.

Look here for info on the server side: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

Please note that Stripe only makes charges when the amount is in cents, so be sure to multiply my amount by 100 before making the charge.